# Playwright test in typescript in visual studio code fails without reason when run in debug mode

Tags: typescript, macos, visual-studio-code, playwright

I've relatively new to typescript and playwright but not so much to coding so I'd say I have a fair idea of what Im attempting to achieve and can't see a logical reason why it doesn't work so I'm hoping someone might be able to aid me...

I have a spec.ts file with a test in, as usual, and this in turn calls a method from a .ts file which has been written to call multiple other methods from a second .ts file.

I've set it up like this because one file has all the individual API calls in, whereas the second file calls a selection of these in specific order so that my tests can just focus on getting a case to the state I want before I then complete the actual test I want, enabling me to write the tests with less lines, I split it between two ts files to help compartmentalise what was held where for my own sanity.

The issue I have is, if I call the individual API call methods directly from my test they work fine, but the moment I put the collection into a method in a second ts file and attempt to call it via that it errors, and if I try and step through it to debug when I get to the first post and attempt to run it it just exits right back to the test level with a failure.

So the individual API call .ts file has an entry looking like this: -

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import {APIRequestContext, expect, request} from '@playwright/test';

module.exports = {
    authorisation: async function ( request: any ){
        dotenv.config();
        
        const response = await request.post(`myURL`, {
                    
            data: {     
                stuffs
            }
            });
    
        const token = JSON.parse(await response.text());
        return token.access_token;
    }
}
```

If I call that from a test that looks like this it works fine,

```
import { test, expect, request, APIRequestContext } from '@playwright/test';

const API_Calls = require("./common/API_Calls");

test('Do the thing', async ({ page, request }) => {    
  var authtoken = await API_Calls.authorisation(request);
  ...draw the rest of the owl...
});
```

But If I create a "collection" .ts file designed to make all the calls in turn like this

```
import {expect, request} from '@playwright/test';
const API_Calls = require("./API_Calls");

module.exports = {

    doAllTheThingsForMe: async function (ADetailsJson: string, BDetailsJson: string, request: any){

        const authtoken = await API_Calls.authorisation(request); <--this is where it dies
        ...do the rest of the owls...
}
```

And then write a test like this to run it

```
test('Do that long test', async ({page}) => {
  var finalResponse = Group_API_Calls.doAllTheThingsForMe("AString","BString");
  const responseCode = finalResponse.status();


  ...owls all the way down...
});
```

It will literally just drop out at the point I've marked as I try to step over it in debug mode.  The error reads: -

```
 1) My Testies API.spec.ts:49:5 › Do that long test
 ─────────────────────────────

    TypeError: finalResponse.status is not a function

      50 |   var finalResponse = Group_API_Calls._doAllTheThingsForMe("AString","BString");
      51 |
    > 52 |   const responseCode = finalResponse.status();
         |                                      ^
      53 |
      54 | });
      55 |
```

If I put all the individual calls into a test and run them that way that will also work, but I was hoping I wouldn't need to write 20 lines of code to run a bunch of the same API tests every single time I want to test something 90% of the way down the track...

I've omitted all the other methods/code that's not being reached as I figured its not applicable but if there's anything people think might be worth looking at let me know and I can update.

Any suggestions gratefully received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is that you do not `await` at the `var finalResponse = Group_API_Calls.doAllTheThingsForMe("AString","BString");`.

Since `doAllTheThingsForMe` is `async` it will return a promise. And if you want to use the actual returned value, you need to `await` it first.

so

```
var finalResponse = await Group_API_Calls.doAllTheThingsForMe("AString","BString");`
```

Comment: I... can't... believe I missed that... ‍♂️ thank you!  As soon as I can I will award the bounty to you!